# What databases/datastores have client data sync support for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, database, nosql

It seems most apps are writing custom logic to sync/replicate cloud data, or using a platform locked service like iCloud.

What cross platform data sync solutions are out there besides roll your own?  By "solution" I mean well tested combinations of server and client components.

The two I know of are:

- **CouchBase Mobile (CouchDB on server, CouchDB on device)**
- **Microsoft Sync Framework (SQL Server on server, SQLite on device)**

I know these are quite different data stores, but any data solution that is generalized for many problem types could potentially reduce some wheel reinventing.  For example I may need NoSQL for one app and relational for another.

Any other options besides these two?

Comment: 12 years have passed. Do you have any updated suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sybase SQL Anywhere Studio has [UltraLite](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1002288#ultralite) database as a part.
This database has versions running on iOS, Android, Blackberry, and lets you [synchronize](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1091125#UL) through HTTP/HTTPS